# Replace DataSource for Reporting Services RDLC Reports

Tags: reporting-services, datasource, rdlc

I am making some changes and need to change the DataSource for my report. How can I do that without losing all of the work I have done? Assume the field names are the same.

Update: The reports are still in Visual Studio and I need to change from a TableAdapter to a DataTable which I will fill through a class.

Update 2: Currently it is using fields in CustomerService_report_vw_ServiceRequest, I want to change that to CustomerService_ServiceRequest. I am seeing this in the expression editor. So when I select the Fields option in the Expression Editor, I want to see the fields in CustomerService_ServiceRequest.

Does that make more sense?

Update 3: So if you add a field from the other DataTable, you can switch your DataSetName to the new one. Now, how do I remove the old one?

Comment: changing the report or changing the data source?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manually edited the *rldc file in a text editor and edited the XML therein to removed the DataSet.

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a life saver. I'd tried a lot of things but manually editing the .rdlc file just like you mentioned solved my problem. Do not also forget to update its respective .xsd file to match the edits you made to the .rdlc file. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the reports uploaded to the report server, the simplest thing would be to go into the properties of your report and then configure the data source information in there.

More information: [Setting Data Source Properties in Reporting Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156018(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: The reports are still in Visual Studio and I need to change from a TableAdapter to a DataTable which I will fill through a class.